# how can I set destination based on username for ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

While connecting via ssh to a server and using differing usernames I keep landing into different devices. I do believe ssh tunneling must be involved somehow, but I cannot figure out how is this achieved.

Quick example:

`ssh user_deviceA@server` -> routed internally to device A -> then I have to introduce the credentials for `user@192.168.1.10`

`ssh user_deviceB@server` -> routed internally to device B -> then I have to introduce the credentials for `user@192.168.1.11`

In this example the private Ip addresses of device A and B are `192.168.1.10` and `192.168.1.11` respectively.

Comment: SSH proxy configurations.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Do you mean `Match User` and `ForceCommand`?